# iMacros - Extract strings using the xpath and loop commands

Tags: loops, firefox, imacros

I want to extract strings using the `xpath` and `loop` commands.

I want to extract a character string from xpath where the value of tr increases by one.

```
①/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/div[1]/a
②/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div[1]/a
```

But when I play loop it only extracts the value of the first string. The code is below.

```
SET !LOOP 1
TAG XPATH="/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{{!LOOP}}]/td[3]/div/div[1]/a" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!VAR1}}
```

> OS:Firefox81.0 VERSION BUILD=10021450

Comment: Mini-"fake" Comment meant for Mods...: Any chance the pending Edit on this Qt could be approved/disapproved by some "Trusted User"...? The Edit has been Pending for more than 24h, and the OP is hardly readable..., and I cannot edit it myself (if needed) as the "other" Edit is "blocking" the Process...

Comment: Oh...!, good...!, the Edit has "finally" been approved... OP/Qt looks fine to me now..., and is much more readable indeed. Perfect... - Now "waiting" for @OP for some Follow-up... (on my Answer)...

Answer (score 0):

Your Script looks OK to me..., I repost it as your OP is a bit difficult to read as you didn't use any Formatting and some Edit is already pending, so I cannot edit it myself...:

```
SET !LOOP 1
TAG XPATH="/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{{!LOOP}}]/td[3]/div/div[1]/a" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!VAR1}}
```

Probably easier anyway than using 'XPATH' would be to use 'Relative Positioning'...
=> Anything in 'TD[1]' or 'TD[2]' (or any other Cell after 'TD[3]') that you could use as 'Anchor'...?

And otherwise, if the 'TABLE' is the only 'TABLE' on the Page, I would expect the following one to work, using twice 'Double Relative Positioning', Technique I've many times explained on the iMacros Forum...:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R{{!LOOP}} TYPE=TR ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R3 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
PROMPT EXTRACT:<SP>_{{!EXTRACT}}_
```

Apart from the last=real 'EXTRACT', all the 'EXTRACT' x4 before are possibly not needed if all those Elements are not "clickable", and the Script can very probably be simplified but you didn't provide any URL, so I can't have a look at the Page and its HTML Structure...

Comment: And the Follow-up is superbly impressive, 3 days later...! => @OP, any Progress/Follow-up...!?